# How can I display a FloatVector without it being editable by the user?

Tags: python, scripting, properties, operator

I am writing a python script that takes some user input in the operator and does a calculation. The result is three floats, which I would like to display in a nice form like FloatVector but I don’t want them to be editable. This would produce unexpected results. I passed in only a get() function to the parameter constructor to make a read-only result, but now I can’t set the values via code.

What is the ‘blender way’ of showing data to the user in a ui panel, and if there is none, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [disable the row](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.enabled) (makes it read-only) and set [`emboss`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=emboss#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) to `False` for example:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    # ...
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(my_data, "my_prop", emboss=False, text="Values")
    row.enabled = False
```

**Or** you can use a label:

```
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Values: {}".format("  ".join(map(str, my_data.my_prop))))
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect! Had no idea about disable row!

Comment: Thanks for expanding and enhancing my answer @brockmann ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Read only property**

> I passed in only a `get()` function to the parameter constructor to make
> a read-only result, but now I can’t set the values via code.

Confused as to why you think cannot just set the value of a read only property in the get method.

Silly example, in the main thread sets the value of `_booble_gooble` to (1, 2, 3)  This  value is used by the float property getter.

This way you have a truly read only property, not one that is being masked in the UI, but possibly available to alter in the custom properties.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from random import random

_booble_gooble = (random(), random(), random())

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(scene, "read_only_float")


def random_value(self):
    # self is scene    
    return _booble_gooble

def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.read_only_float = FloatVectorProperty(get=random_value)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _booble_gooble = (1, 2, 3) # set it
    register()
```